# view android calender view month vise

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-activity

I have added a **calender view** for my **android** application and it shows dates continually. but what I want is show month vise dates. calender view in my activity is as below.

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

and it display like this.
[image]

can I show the dates month vise using java. Is it possible. Thank you!